# Why can't I loop through {data} array after API call?

Tags: charge

I'm using the Charge API to get a customer's next invoice date in a template:

```
{exp:charge:api call="Stripe_Invoice::upcoming" param_name="customer" key="{customer_id}"}
{if has_error}
    {error_message}
{if:else}
    {data}
        {if '{next_payment_attempt}' != ''}
            Your plan will renew automatically on:
            {exp:low_nice_date date="{next_payment_attempt}" format="%n/%j/%Y"}.
        {/if}
    {/data}
{/if}
{/exp:charge:api}
```

This calls the `api()` function in the module, and I can clearly see where `{data}` is being set:

```
$data = ee()->charge_stripe->api_call($call_name, $call_val, $call_param_name);

if ($data === false) {
    $ret['has_error'] = true;
    $ret['error_message'] = ee()->charge_stripe->api_error_message;
} else {
    $ret['data'] = $data;
    $ret['has_error'] = false;
    $ret['error_message'] = '';
}
```

If I `var_dump($data['next_payment_attempt'])` there I get a timestamp, as expected.  But in the template I get an error about Array to String conversion.  I can manually add the line `$ret['next_payment_attempt'] = $data['next_payment_attempt'];` and then use `{next_payment_attempt}` in my template.

Why can't I use `{data}{next_payment_attempt}{/data}` in my template without modifying the PHP directly, when it's clear that `$data['next_payment_attempt']` is a timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas I don't know the add-on, but for a tag pair, it needs to be a numerical indexed array for the return variable, so `$ret['data'] = $data` would need to be `$ret['data'] = array($data)`, so that the variable pair has something to loop through, so the output should be in this structure: `$ret['data'][0]['next_payment_attempt']` - even if it only contains 1 set of data (1 loop).

Comment: Sure enough, I edited the PHP to do `$ret['data'] = array($data)` and now everything works as expected